# Send messages to client with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, sails.js

I have a server side application, which implements Rest API for client Http requests.

I have a request for deleting MongoDB docs for many schemas.

I want to send to the client realtime object status about the delete proccessing like:
Status: {
xSchema: "DONE"
}
And then
Status: {
xSchame: "DONE",
ySchame: "DONE"
}

This object will send to the client When each step of the delete proccessing is done.

I thought about using socket.io for this operation, do you guys have any other ideas or example how to do it?
What's the best practices for this?

I want to send these status without client requests.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Using websocket is how it is usually implemented, so socket.io should be good.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to something like this, where you will be sending a result object with success status and status message in a json format to the client side.

```
router.get('/profile/:username', (req, res, next) => {
  User.findOne({ username: req.params.username }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    }
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.json({ success: true, status: 'User Retrieved Successfully!', user: user });
  })
});
```